# Need iPhone card flip effect , can't figure out how to do it

Tags: iphone

I'm writing a card game and need a animation to flip them over from one side to the other along the y axses.  What would be the easiest way to do this? Is there any good tutors?
This is what I did:

Found some sample code for using UITransitionView.  But it comes up as undeclared on my sdk,   and I found out this was undocumented.
   Looked into OpenGL, seems to complicated.

Any help would be GREAT!
Ted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that I used in a blackjack app tutorial I went through:

```
-(void) flipCard {

[UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip Top Card" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(flipCardDone)];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut ];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:topCard cache:YES];

topCard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]; //begin
topCard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:currentName]; //end 

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

```
-(void) flipCardDone {

topCard.hidden = YES;
nextCardToFlip.hidden = NO; // bad var name, nextCardToFlip ONLY appears to flip.
}
```

I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to use UIView transitions, or CATransitions depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Documentation for the UIView animation can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView%3atoView%3aduration%3aoptions%3acompletion%3a).